How do I search all files in the current directory for a string and save the file name and the line containing that string to variables in Batch?
I have ASC files of CAN messages. I want to look through all the CAN messages in a folder and sort them into new folders based on the values of a specific message. Something like:
for all .asc files (
   find "FF52"
   if found (
      set result=(full line containing FF52)
      make a new folder based on stuff in that line
      put a copy of the file in the new folder
   )
)

There may be multiple lines containing different data with that message so I need to process each line that contains FF52. Here's a couple things I've tried:
@echo on

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%a in (*.asc) do (
    FIND "FF52" %%a
)

This much works and I get:
---------- UNIT1-DAY1.ASC
0.342718625 1  18FF52D0x    Rx   d   8 8F 00 FF FF 64 64 64 64
0.352662125 1  18FF52D0x    Rx   d   8 99 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00
0.353253875 1  18FF5299x    Rx   d   8 D0 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00
0.552910375 1  18FF52D0x    Rx   d   8 8F 00 FF FF 64 64 64 64
0.553474375 1  18FF528Fx    Rx   d   8 D0 00 FF FF 64 64 64 64

I want to be able to set variables like:
Line1=0.342718625 1  18FF52D0x    Rx   d   8 8F 00 FF FF 64 64 64 64

Also tried:
for %%a in (*.asc) do (
   set "Line=FIND "FF52" %%a"
   echo %Line%
)

and it returns:
set "Line=FIND "FF52" Unit1-Day1.asc"
 echo
)
ECHO is on.

Also tried:
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%a in (*.asc) do (
    set Line=
    @findstr :"FF52" "%%~a"
    @findstr :"FF52" "%%~a" > %Line%
    echo.
    echo %Line%
    pause
)

And it doesn't work.
I can only find results for iterating line by line to do this but it requires a for loop and I need a for loop to go through all the files and I can't find much on making nested for loops work.

Markdown help
